# Multiple Select Widgets in Jquery mobile is not working in Android 2.3

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am developing Android native mobile application using Jquery Mobile 1.3.1 + phone gap. 
Below code is not working (option's doesn't popup) in Android 2.3 but the same works fine in Android 4. 
Any thoughts/suggestions for making this work in Android 2.3 devices.

```
<div id="createOrderHolder">

<ul id="fmcgProdList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"
data-filter-placeholder="Search Products" data-inset="true">
    <li id="8" class="productListClass" >
              <input id="8" name="8" type="checkbox" />
              <label class="prodLabel" for="8" >Bisleri Water</label>
              <p style="font-size: 1em;" >
                 <strong>Quantity:</strong>
                 <select id="select2" >
                    <option value="1" >1</option>
                    <option value="2" >2</option>
                    <option value="3" >3</option>
                    <option value="4" >4</option>
                    <option value="5" >5</option>
                    <option value="6" >6</option>
                 </select>
             </p>
          </li>
          <li id="9" class="productListClass" >
              <input id="9" name="8" type="checkbox" />
               <label class="prodLabel" for="9" >Bisleri Water</label>
                <p style="font-size: 1em;" >
                   <strong>Quantity:</strong>
                       <select id="select1" >
                       <option value="1" >1</option>
                       <option value="2" >2</option>
                       <option value="3" >3</option>
                       <option value="4" >4</option>
                       <option value="5" >5</option>
                       <option value="6" >6</option>
                      </select>
               </p>
        </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

One more observation if i have only one list item it works fine but if add one more list item it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `data-native-menu="false"` to your `<select>` to make it popout.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/yKEz4/

Comment: if you think this has helped you, pls consider marking it as the answer :)

Comment: can you suggest what option should be set in case of if i have horizontal group of selects in a <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

Comment: By adding the data-type="horizontal" attribute to the controlgroup container, you can swap to a horizontal-style group that floats the buttons side-by-side